# How to display duplicate values only once in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have list that is returning `category` and `subcategory` and displaying it using `ng-repeat` but I want to display the category only once.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allocationList">
   <p>Category:{{item.Category}}</p>
   <p>SubCategory:{{item.subCategory}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for: Category1
Sub1
Sub2
Sub3
Category2
Sub1
Sub2?

Comment: Can you share the Data ?

Comment: Ya Chris G I want something like that Category1 Sub1 Sub2 Sub3 Category2 Sub1 Sub2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include below scripts inside *.html file:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

Change your module definition statement to:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

And retrieve item as shown below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in allocationList | unique:'category'">
   <p>Category:{{item.Category}}</p>
   <p>SubCategory:{{item.subCategory}}</p>
</div>
```

I hope it helped :)

Comment: but here its filtering the rows also I want only category name to display once and rest all the rows should come